# Use mysql variable for millisecond precision in DATETIME

Tags: mysql, variables, datetime, set, milliseconds

I am trying to execute this sql script :

```
SET @microSecondPrecision:=3;

CREATE TABLE DATA_OHLCV (date DATETIME(@microSecondPrecision) NOT NULL);'
```

and I get an sql syntaxe error. I tried to use SELECT @microSecondPrecision; instead of @microSecondPrecision but still I get a sql syntaxe error.

I cannot find how to une my variable.
Can someone help me please ?

Thank you in advance for your help.
`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the precision has to be a constant.  You can do what you what with a `prepare`/`execute` statement.

Comment: I also tried '{$microSecondPrecision}' and still doesn't work

Comment: Its contant in my script its just that I use the same precision for a lot of table and it very tedious to change them all